# Problema al usar $.ajax con safari

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo la siguiente situación, estoy usando un **$.ajax POST** para enviar datos al servidor pero tengo un detalle, cuando cargo el sitio en un navegador **Safari** ya sea en una **Mac** o en un **Ipad** el proceso no se me ejecuta y se me queda cargando en:

```
 beforeSend: function(){
                                message = $("<div class='alert alert-danger'><span class='before'>Subiendo, por favor espere...</span></div>");
                                showMessage(message)        
                            }
```

Buscando en **internet** encontré un problema similar, en el cual solo tenían que agregar las siguientes lineas:

```
                        async: true,
                        headers: {
                            "cache-control": "no-cache"
                          },
```

Las agregue pero el problema no se me soluciona. A continuación les dejos el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

> Nota: No me genera ningún error en la consola de desarrollado de
>   **Safari**.

Gracias.

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "index.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        async: true,
                        headers: {
                            "cache-control": "no-cache"
                          },                                
                        //mientras enviamos el archivo
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            message = $("<div class='alert alert-danger'><span class='before'>Subiendo, por favor espere...</span></div>");
                            showMessage(message)        
                        },                                
                        success: function (datos) {
                            if(!id){
                                $("input#idnombre").val("");
                                $("textarea#idatalle").val("");
                                $('select#grupo').prop('selectedIndex',-1);
                                $('select#id_usuario').prop('selectedIndex',-1);
                            }
                            //$("textarea#idatalle").val("");
                            $("div#iderror").html(datos);
                        },
                        //si ha ocurrido un error
                        error: function(){
                            message = $('<div class="alert alert-danger">Ha ocurrido un error.</div>');
                            $( "#accion" ).prop( "disabled", false );
                            showMessage(message);
                        }                                
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Les dejo la solución a este problema que tenia con safari en el **$.ajax**.

Lo que sucede es que **safati**, no permites elementos **empty** cuando se esta usando **input file** en el formulario. El campo lo estaba pasando vació, por lo que me provocaba que la función de **$.ajax** se me quedara detenida en  **beforeSend**  provocando un **timeaout** en la ejecución.

La solución que represento es para el caso que se este usando **FormData** para capturar los datos del formulario.

Gracias.

```
var dataString = new FormData($(this)[0]);

if (document.getElementById("id elemento input file").files.length == 0 ) {
    dataString.delete("nombre del elemento input file"); 
}
```